# Add Twitter feeds for the SE family for support and feature announcements

Tags: feature-request, communication

I'd like to know about things in advance.  It would be nice if significant changes/issues could be announced via Twitter for those of us who use it.  I suppose a Facebook page might work as well, though I suspect the overlap between Stack Overflow/Twitter is probably greater.  No reason you couldn't do both and have the tweets automatically published to the Facebook page.  Tweets could link to relevant discussions on Meta and/or the blog for more information.

I think this would go a long way in solving some communication issues both in disseminating and finding information about what changes are being made.